# I want to parse system log file into csv format

Tags: python, csv

> not running?'  Jan 23 16:54:16 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: The
>   command '/usr/local/etc/rc.d/radiusd.sh stop' returned exit code '1',
>   the output was 'radiusd not running?'
>
> Jan 23 16:54:19 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: [FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC
>   sync is starting with timeout 150 seconds.
>
> Jan 23 16:54:19 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: [FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC
>   Sync with '20.20.20.2' aborted due to the following error(s):
>   Misconfigured Replication Target Port.
>
> Jan 23 16:54:19 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: [FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC
>   sync is ending.
>
> Jan 23 16:54:19 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: The command
>   '/usr/local/etc/rc.d/radiusd.sh stop' returned exit code '1', the
>   output was 'radiusd not running?'
>
> Jan 23 16:54:21 pfsense php: rc.start_packages: [FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC
>   sync is starting with timeout 150 seconds.

**I want to parse above data of system log files into a csv file via python. Firstly I tried the following code**

```
    import csv
    import itertools 

    with open('system.log', 'r') as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
        grouped = zip(*[lines] * 7)
        with open('system.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(('month', 'day', 
    'time','pfsense','type','package','comment'))
            writer.writerows(grouped)
```

**Headers were perfectly coming but the file wasn't actually converting to csv. Hence, I converted the file into delimited text file and parsed with following code.**

```
    import csv
    with open('systemExcel.txt', "r") as infile, open('systeExcel.csv', 'w') 
    as outfile:in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = '\t')
        out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
        out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

**Above code is working perfectly fine. But I need a script that can convert the raw log file data into csv file with headers.**

Comment: Can you add your code what you have done ?

Comment: `import csv
import itertools 

with open('system.log', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
    grouped = zip(*[lines] * 7)
    with open('system.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('month', 'day', 'time','pfsense','type','package','comment'))
        writer.writerows(grouped)`

@JayParikh

Comment: can you edit your quesiton and post your code in proper format ? It's not readable in comments

Comment: done @JayParikh

Comment: I think you are posting here first time. could you also tell us what problem you are facing in your code

Comment: @JayParikh Yes. I'm sorry for inconvenience. please check. I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: ...  I need a script that can convert the raw log file data into csv file with headers.

Read and write only **one** line of data.
Consider this examples:

```
with open('system.csv', 'w') as out_file,
    open('system.log', 'r') as in_file:

    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(['month', 'day','time', 'pfsense', 'type', 'package', 'comment'])

    for line in in_file:
        columns = line[:-1].split(' ')
        columns[6] = ' '.join(columns[6:])
        writer.writerow(columns[:7])
```

> **Output**:
>   month,day,time,pfsense,type,package,comment
>   Jan,23,16:54:16,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,The command... (omitted for brevity)
>   Jan,23,16:54:19,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,[FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC... (omitted for brevity)
>   Jan,23,16:54:19,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,[FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC... (omitted for brevity)
>   Jan,23,16:54:19,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,[FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC... (omitted for brevity)
>   Jan,23,16:54:19,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,The command... (omitted for brevity)
>   Jan,23,16:54:21,pfsense,php:,rc.start_packages:,[FreeRADIUS]: XMLRPC... (omitted for brevity)

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Thank you! @stovfl